# jinja2 filter causing dict object has no attribute error

Tags: flask, jinja2

Why is this throwing the errors below? This is in the .html file for presentation to the user

```
{% for year,data in data_inputs.data_set.items() %}
    {{ data.data_point }} \\ WORKS; output is 10
    {{ data.data_point|int }} \\ Throws "dict object has no attribute 'data_point' error"
    {{ data.data_point - 2 }} \\ Throws "dict object has no attribute 'data_point' error"
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: try this out : `{{ data["data_point"]|int }}`

Comment: Also to no avail @cizario unfortunately...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to check all items; one of them did indeed not have the right data_point - though was coming out as blank until you try and perform an operator on it subsequently...